# Why Clebsch–Gordan coefficients does not have a recursion relation for $J$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, representation-theory

The Clebsch–Gordan coefficients had a recursion relation: Sakurai Eq 3.8.45

$$J_\pm|j_1j_2; jm\rangle =(j_{1\pm}+j_{2\pm}) \sum_{m_1} \sum_{m_2} |j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle\langle j_1j_2;m_1m_2| j_1j_2;jm\rangle$$

Thus if one started say $|j_1=1j_2=1|J=2M=2\rangle$ one could obtain the representation of $|J=2$, $M=2,1,0,-1,-2\rangle$.

However, why there's not a recursion relationship for $J$?  i.e. although one could use orthogonal relationship to calculate for $|J=1M=1\rangle$, why there's not a recursion relationship like that for $M$?

Comment: $J_{\pm}$, in the Lie algebra of the rotation group,  move you within a rep labelled by J, so do not hop to another rep. To hop to another rep, different J, you need operators *outside* the algebra, such as Runge-Lenz operators. This is exactly how Pauli solved the Hydrogen atom before Schroedinger and his equation!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Did you mean $I=(L+N)/2$ and $K=(L-N)/2$ operator (Sakurai chapter 4.1 Symmetries from page 266 to Eq 4.1.37 $E=-\frac{mZ^2 e^4}{2\hbar^2} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}$)?  But the ket space was orthogonal. The orthogonal should be able to be expressed in some sort of relationship.

Comment: I'm not familiar in detail with his treatment, but that sounds right; to the extent that *N* does not commute with $L^2$, it connects different *J*s in your language. I have seen this hopping in the spectrum-generating chapter of B Wybourne's *Classical Groups for physicists*  book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do.  Obviously they are not generated by the action of $J_\pm$ since this action cannot change the $J$ quantum number but if my typesetting is right two of them are
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{\frac{2c(-a+b+c)(a+b+c+1)}{2c+1}}C^{c\gamma}_{a\alpha b\beta}\\
&=\sqrt{(b-\beta)(c-\gamma)}C^{c-1/2,\gamma-1/2}_{a\alpha,b\beta-1/2}
+\sqrt{(b+\beta)(c+\gamma)}C^{c-1/2,\gamma-1/2}_{a\alpha-1/2,b\beta}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\sqrt{\frac{(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c+1)(a+b+c+1)(2c-1)}{2c+1}}
C^{c\gamma}_{a\alpha,b\beta}\nonumber \\
&\quad =\sqrt{(b+\beta)(b-\beta+1)(c+\gamma)(c+\gamma-1)}C^{c-1,\gamma-1}_{a\alpha,b\beta-1}-2\beta\sqrt{c^2-\gamma^2}C^{c-1,\gamma}_{a\alpha,b\beta}\\
&\qquad -\sqrt{(b-\beta)(b+\beta+1)(c-\gamma)(c-\gamma-1)}C^{c-1,\gamma+1}_{a\alpha,b\beta+1}
\end{align}
and more are given in

> Varshalovich, D. A., Moskalev, A. N., & Khersonskii, V. K. M. (1988). Quantum theory of angular momentum.

I believe are consequences of recursion relations of Regge symbols.  See also along those lines

> Bincer, A. M. (1970). Interpretation of the Symmetry of the Clebsch‐Gordan Coefficients Discovered by Regge. Journal of Mathematical Physics, 11(6), 1835-1844.

Another paper

> Smorodinskiĭ, Y. A., & Shelepin, L. A. (1972). Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, viewed from different sides. Soviet Physics Uspekhi, 15(1), 1.

gives a completely cool approach to obtaining some unexpected relations which can be transformed into recursion relations.